# We can make an http request on node.js with the client IP address?

Tags: node.js, http, request, ip, client

I'm noob with node.js but I know node.js is a server side language so when we make an http request we probably use the server IP address, right ?

I want to know if there any solution to use the client IP address when I wan to make an http request ?

Sorry for my bad English.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming you're trying to make an http request to your node server. If so, then it's not possible because your client has their own IP address which is distinct from that of the server.

Comment: Sorry my english is poor, no I mean about making a http request from my node server to another website.

Comment: Are you trying to perform a redirect to another website? Or make an API call to a service provided by that site to send/retrieve data?

Comment: Yes I try to make an API call to a service to retrieve data.
And I want to know if I can use the client/user IP address to do it.

Comment: That shouldn't be possible since you're making an API call to the server (where the API is hosted) and not to the client.